# WPBakery Accordion failure

Tags: wordpress, function, themes, accordion, default

I have a problem with the **WPBakery accordion function**.

When i create an accordion, it won't show the function on the custom Theme. All Content of the headings are shown, and don't react on click.

When I change the view to one of the default themes, it does function.
No classes are overwritten or disturbed by custom styles or struktures of the theme.

Timber and Guzzle, Bootstrap, font-awesome, jquerie, popper, prop-types, react, react-dom, slick-carusel, babel, sass loader are used on the custom template.

I've been trying to delete some features to see if something intervenes with the accordion, but this didn't brought any results.

Now I don't know how I can find the problem, that is disturbing the accordion-function of WPBakery.

Answer (score 1):

WP Bakery accordions load their styling from `/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer_tta.min.css` . You can see that all styling rules there start by `.wpb-js-composer`class definition, so check if you have this class in your HTML output, it should be added to your `<body>` element.

If it is missing, it is probably because your theme's body element doesn't have system classes bound. You can fix it by adding `<?php body_class(); ?>` call there, so it looks like:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Then the accordions styling should bind properly.

Answer (score 0):

Open the page where you place the accordion & go to **Console** by inspect.

If you see any error then copy that & mention here.

OR just provide the website link. will try to figure it out.

Comment: sadly there aren't any errors that are mentioned in the console.

Comment: at the moment the website isn't free for official servers and is located on the local pc via xampp

Comment: Then without the real view it's very hard to guess what's the problem.